# Setting UserPrincipal in form based authentication

Tags: java, security, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

[JEE, MVC-JSP+Servlets, TomEE]

Using form based declarative authentication (container managed). Is it possible to explicitly set `UserPrincipal`? (to log some user in).

I know I can check whether there is logged in user or not with `request.getUserPrincipal()!=null`.

Actually I am facing following situation: I have a `register.jsp` that is being used for new users registration. So data from this jsp are sent to servlet where new user object is created  and persisted to database. So, now when user has registered, he/she should be automatically logged in. So, I was thinking how can I implement this automatic login after registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Servlet 3.0 and above, use [`HttpServletRequest.login()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).